# Full Example Of JSRequest In SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, url, parameter

I am trying to get JSRequest.QueryString working.

I have seen numerous examples like the following:

```
//First we must call the EnsureSetup method
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 

//Get a query string parameter called Id. i.e - "page.aspx?Id=11" will return 11
itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["Id"];

//Get the current page name. i.e - "default.aspx"
itemId = JSRequest.FileName;

//Get the current path name. i.e - "/itaysk/doclib/default.aspx"
itemId = JSRequest.PathName;
```

But none of the examples I can find explain where to put the code above or what dependencies I need to include.

Could somebody post a full working example of where the above code should be defined (e.g. does it have to go into the markup or can it be in a CEWP or into an included javascript file or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 4):

`JSRequest` is OOB SharePoint JavaScript Object. If you want to use it in CEWP, wrap it insie the script tag. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//First we must call the EnsureSetup method
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 

//Get a query string parameter called Id. i.e - "page.aspx?Id=11" will return 11
itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["Id"];

//Get the current page name. i.e - "default.aspx"
itemId = JSRequest.FileName;

//Get the current path name. i.e - "/itaysk/doclib/default.aspx"
itemId = JSRequest.PathName;
</script>
```